# What are they doing in this piece of code (Assigning $({}) to an object property)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, publish-subscribe, assign

What is happening to the seeming "obj" property that is followed by : $({}) I searched online and can't seem to figure out what that is. The closest I got is to assuming it is jquery utility tools; but even then I am unable to find any examples that use it as such.

```js
function() {
    window.SomePage || (window.SomePage = {}),
    SomePage.PubSub = {
        obj: $({}),
        publish: function() {
            return this.obj.trigger.apply(this.obj, arguments)
        },
        subscribe: function() {
            return this.obj.on.apply(this.obj, arguments)
        },
        unsubscribe: function() {
            return this.obj.off.apply(this.obj, arguments)
        }
    }
}
.call(this)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _"What is happening to the seeming "obj""_? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `jQuery()` function can accept a string, an existing jQuery object, a function or an array as parameter. Though the pattern `$([])` does not return same result as `$({})`. When a string is passed the string is expected to be a CSS selector, e.g., `$("div")`, or creation of an element `$("<div>")`. When a function is passed, the function is expected to be called as parameter for `.ready()`, as `jQuery()` is also an alias for `.ready()`, until `.ready()` is fully deprecated. The code at Question essentially uses `$({})` to chain jQuery methods, instead of using a jQuery wrapped element in `DOM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$({})` creates a jQuery object by calling `jQuery()` with a plain JavaScript object as parameter which allows jQuery methods such as `.trigger()` and `.on()` to be chained to the created jQuery object reference.

What you do with the jQuery object is up to you. For example, you can chain `.queue()` to an instance of `$({})`

```js
$({}).queue("props", function(next) {
  console.log(123)
}).dequeue("props")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```